# BigQuery: Load JSON object as a string

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a new line delimited json with 3 fields: 2 of them are strings, the 3rd is a json object. Here is an example:

```
{"val1":"stringvalue1","val2":"stringvalue2","val3":{"i1":789,"i2":60.0,"i3":8}}
```

I would like to load the file directly with all 3 fields as STRING.

The 3rd field would be "{"i1":789,"i2":60.0,"i3":8}" here.

I don't know how many fields the JSON object in val3 will contain: it's different between each lines. Is there a way to just directly convert the JSON object to a string ? I tried specifying the column as string in the schema, but I got a parsing error while loading.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a maximum of fields in val3 you can expect - like i10 ? If so, create the table first and load the file into it. Unassigned i* will default to null

Answer (score 2):

1. Load as single column CSV.

   a. Make sure to set the field separator character to a rare one, or just null (`\0`).
2. That will load the whole row as a single column.
3. Parse the text row inside BigQuery. Either with the native JSON functions, or with Javascript. In this case, the native BigQuery JSON functions should be enough.

Comment: This is a hack, BigQuery should cooerce JSON objects as string or as RECORD.
Especially when used with `EXTERNAL TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see this format `"{"i1":789,"i2":60.0,"i3":8}"` makes it incorrect (look at opening and closing `"`.

You have to convert it into string so it looks like this `"{\"i1\":789,\"i2\":60.0,\"i3\":8}"`.

I used `jq` python library to do it. Something like

```
jq.compile("tostring").input(your_input_json).text()
```

And then when I loaded this json to bigquery (via google cloud storage in my case) it was breeze,

The Google Storage file looked like this

```
"{\"i1\":789,\"i2\":60.0,\"i3\":8}"
```

and bigquery had columns with value

```
{"i1":789,"i2":60.0,"i3":8}
```